# Blacklisting audio driver kills ALSA

Tags: driver, alsa

I am trying to create a simple driver for my PCI sound card in which I will use the ALSA api. And of course I face a problem: I can't make my driver work.

So here are some details:

1. As I mentioned my sound card is a PCI device. In order to start my driver I had to stop the originally running snd_intel8x0 driver, as it had occupied the device and it was not accessible(the probe function of my driver was never executed). So I blacklisted the snd_intel8x0 driver (added line in /etc/modporbe.d/blacklist.conf).
   From this moment on my driver can be started - the probe function is started.
2. Unfortunately when snd_intel8x0 driver is blacklisted ALSA api also seems to disappear. I observe the following:

   - when I start my driver I get these errors in dmesg:

[...] alsa: Unknown symbol snd_card_register (err 0)

[...] alsa: Unknown symbol snd_card_create (err 0)

[...] alsa: Unknown symbol snd_card_free (err 0)

[...] alsa: Unknown symbol snd_device_new (err 0)

- in file /proc/kallsyms there are no snd* symbols (if the original driver snd_intel8x0 is running all of the above mentioned snd* functions are available in /proc/kallsyms)
- there is folder /proc/asound (if snd_intel8x0 is running asound folder is present)

So my questions:

1. How can I make my PCI audio card use my driver and not snd_intel8x0?
2. How do I make ALSA available for my driver?
3. In general: why does ALSA disappear when snd_intel8x0 is blacklisted?

Thank you in advance
Grts, Nedelin

Answer (score 1):

The driver `snd-intel8x0` is for Intel and compatible AC'97 controllers.
If you have such a controller, `snd-intel8x0` is the correct driver to use.

If your device does require something new, extend the `snd-intel8x0` driver.

If you really want to write a replacement for `snd-intel8x0`, putting the latter into `blacklist.conf` is the correct way.

---

You get "unknown symbol" errors when the modules that are currently loaded and the module you are trying to load are not compatible.
When you recompile ALSA, you should unload all `snd*` modules before loading a new one.

Comment: Hi CL, thanks for the answer.

I am far from a Linux expert, so excuse me if my questions are stupid.

You say: "When you recompile ALSA, you should unload all snd* modules before loading a new one." - it seems exactly what I do: blacklist snd-intel8x0 will remove all snd* modules, as they all use it. Or you refer to something else?

And the main question: I guess I should rebuild somehow ALSA with my driver. How do I do this? Rebuilding Linux kernel?

Comment: Blacklisting will not unload any module that is current loaded. ALSA is part of the kernel; never use the `alsa-driver` package but recompile the kernel itself.

Comment: OK, I spent a lot of time trying to find out how to integrate my driver in the Kernel. Unfortunately all my attempts failed.

I apologize if I ask stupid questions but can you please point me what steps I should follow?

Comment: This is not a forum. That's a different question; don't put it into comments.